# cannot change value of edittext due to textwacher in fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, textwatcher

I have a listview in a fragment. By clicking on listview items ,opens a new fragment to show details.In second detail fragment i have a edittext and have a textwatcher on that edittext.On entering text in edittext textwatcher does its operations.On back button i removed detail fragment and back in listview fragment.
But the problem is when i open detail fragment second time edittext remains with its previous value.textwatcher sets the old fragment value in new detail fragment.so how to deal with it.
Please help me out.

```
public class Recieptlistfrag extends Fragment {.....

RecieptFragment fragment;
SharedPreferences preferences;
............
............


listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
fragment.setArguments(bundle);
getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager()
                        .beginTransaction().add(R.id.container_top, fragment,
                                "RecieptFragment").commit();
...........
```

now in back button of receitfragment

```
getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager()
                            .popBackStackImmediate();
```

edittext with textwatcher...

```
    public static class MyTextWatcher implements TextWatcher
{
     public void onTextChanged(CharSequence cs, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {
            customAdapter.getFilter().filter(cs);
        }

        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {
        }

        public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {
        }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't do :

```
RecieptFragment fragment;
```

Do this :

```
 listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        Fragment fragment = new RecieptFragment();
            fragment.setArguments(bundle);
            getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.container_top, fragment,"RecieptFragment").commit();
```

Hope this will help. :)